# Monotone Likelihood Ratio: Relationship between density and its derivative

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, order-statistics

Let $\{h(z|v)\}$ be a family of densities parametrized by $v$, which satisfies the Monotone Likelihood Ratio property (MLRP). The support of $z$ is $[0,\infty]$ and suppose it has a finite expectation for all $v$. The parameter $v$ is such that
$$
v=\int_0^{\infty} zh(z|v)dz
$$

I am required to prove that
$$
\int_a ^{\infty} z h(z|v)dz \geq v \int_a^{\infty} z \frac{\partial h(z|v)}{\partial v}dz$$
for any $a>0$ and any $h(z|v)$ that satisfies MLRP.

I know that MLRP implies that the density satisfies log supermodularity and total positivity of order $2$, and, thus, that
$$
\frac{\frac{\partial h(z|v)}{\partial v}}{h(z|v)}
$$
is increasing in $z$.
I have been reviewing many of the results from Karlin but nothing comes close.

Very much appreciated.